# Sprite Animation in opengl

Tags: opengl, animation, 2d, sprite

I want to animate a crocodile, but my code does not work properly. When I used `glutSwapBuffer()` in the drawing function of `crocodile`, my screen blinks. If I comment the`glutSwapBuffer`, my crocodile not shown on screen at all.

```
void Timer(int value)
{      
    drawCrocodile(); // 
    croco += 10;
    glutTimerFunc(30, Timer, 1);
    glutPostRedisplay(); 
}


void drawCrocodile()
{
    if (croco<=240)
    {
        glRasterPos2i(-15,-35); // draw croco sleping for sometime
        pix[5].mDraw(); 
    }

    if (croco<=480 && croco>=240) // draw closed croco
    {
        glRasterPos2i(-15,-35);
        pix[6].mDraw();
    }

    if (croco<=720 && croco>=480) // draw mouth open croco
    {
        glRasterPos2i(-15,-35);
        pix[7].mDraw();
    }
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: Do you have a double buffered window? And the ifs are drawing two sprites in frame 240 and 480.

Comment: @BDL Yes , i have a double buffer window, in frame 240 and 480 only 1 pic draw